# Concatenating tree key names

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hash, tree

I have a hash with a tree like shape:

```
{
   "65" => {
      "34" => {
         "18" => {}
       },
      "22" => {
         "44" => {
            "14" => {}
          },
         "81" => {}
      }
   },
   "32" => {
      "44" => {
         "37" =>{}
      }
   }
}
```

I need an array of arrays or any other data structure that has all of the descendant values corresponding to the parent path. I.e.,

```
[["65","34","18"],["65","22","44","14"],["65","22",81"],["32","44","37"]]
```

Is that the best way to go about doing that? If there's a better way to handle the hash, such as using a tree structure, that'd be great. I can find the direct parent to a child, i.e. for `"34"` it's `"65"`, but is there any concept of parent for a hash so that I can point it backwards? Or is that best suited as a node in a tree?

Comment: Edit: Sawa pointed me in the right direction (the duplicate). The difference was between that solution and this is just that I'm dealing with empty hash's as values vs actual values, which isn't a big deal, but something to consider with that answer.

Comment: I don't see why this is a duplicate, as it lends itself to a simpler solution than does @sawa's question: `def find_em(h,f=[],a=[]); return a << f if h.empty?; h.each { |k,h| find_em(h,f + [k],a) }; a; end`, invoked with `find_em(h)`.